# Case sensitive character detection in jQuery's onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to "case-sensitively" detect characters `onkeypress` in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and look at the event's which attribute, as described on that page. That page has a Demo section near the bottom where you can type in 'a' and see that which is 97, and then type in 'A' and see that which is 65.

(By the way, I assume you mean "[case-sensitively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity)" rather than "case-sensibly".)

Answer (score 1):

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HVT5M/)

```
// type 'a': 97
// type 'A': 65
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    console.log(e.which)  
});
```

Comment: e.which contains the key code. e.target contains the element that originated the keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for jQuery, which does only the simplest of normalization. As noted elsewhere, the `keypress` is your only option for key events, and getting the character is pretty simple:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode) {
        alert("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
    }
};
```

Be aware that there a few cases here where you'll get a character alerted for non-printable keys in some browsers, which jQuery wouldn't protect you from (its normalization is almost identical to mine). For more information, see the current definitive reference on JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

I've also written at (slightly) more length on a similar question recently: [JavaScript KeyCode vs CharCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285627/javascript-keycode-vs-charcode-utter-confusion/4285801#4285801)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `string.match()` (a plain javascript function)

More details on: [link text](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-strings/)

Maybe if you give more info we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that this will only work for keypress, so be careful trying to do this with keydown and keyup. This is from the jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) on keypress:

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a
>   code indicating which key is pressed,
>   while keypress indicates which
>   character was entered.