# Issue with ascii keycode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing a wierd issue in javascript, or maybe it's because javascript is new to me.

I am trying to allow some action if onkeypress, but only when alphanumeric or special character is pressed. This is my code:

```
if(e.keyCode>=32 && e.keyCode<=126 ){
    alert(e.keyCode);}
}
```

It does not alert if I press any special character key like `{,]>.` am I missing anything here?

Comment: Could you post your entire code? The above works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LZhSW/

Comment: Does it work when you press a numerical key (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: yes, it does work for numerical key as well. I took the ASCII code from W3 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp , but when i press any special character like [{]{><,.; it does not fall in =>32 and <=126

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyCode` for a comma (`,`) is 188. Could this be why?

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: The key being that `keyCode` is **not** a reference into the ASCII table

Comment: I took referenced from W3schools url http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp  and all special char comes under 32 to 126.. Am I refering wrong website to get ASCII code?

Comment: @user2018223: You shouldn't be looking for ASCII codes at all, because you're using `keyCode`.

Comment: I am new in this field , please let me know how does it differ keyCode from ASCII codes?

Comment: @user2018223: Didn't you read my answer? It contains _tons_ of links explaining this. There is also http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. Please _read_.

Comment: (You also apparently did not read the documentation for `keyCode` before deciding to use it, which is a shame.)

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that `keyCode` gives you an ASCII index, but [that is not true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.keyCode). Your range criteria are incorrect due to this assumption.

[MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.keyCode)

> **In a `keypress` event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in either the `keyCode` or `charCode` property, never both.** If the key pressed generates a character (e.g. 'a'), `charCode` is set to the code of that character, respecting the letter case. (i.e. `charCode` takes into account whether the shift key is held down). Otherwise, the code of the pressed key is stored in `keyCode`.
>
> `keyCode` is always set in the keydown and keyup events. In these cases, charCode is never set.
>
> **To get the code of the key regardless of whether it was stored in `keyCode` or `charCode`, query the which property.**
>
> **For a list of the keyCode values associated with particular keys, run the example in [Example 7: Displaying Event Object Constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_7:_Displaying_Event_Object_Constants) and view the resulting HTML table.**

Doing as instructed reveals that some of your "special" characters lie outside of the range limits you've specified.

Kevin also pointed out [this useful table](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), but you'd be best off using [a more canonical approach to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474860/560648) [keypress handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285801/560648).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `which` property in most browsers and `keyCode` in IE only. You do have the correct event: only `keypress` will do if you're interested in the character typed rather than the physical key pressed.

Here's my favourite reference for this stuff: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    alert("Character typed: " + charTyped);
};
```

Comment: Ah, excellent - I didn't fancy converting your previous answer. :)

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: I seem to churn out variations on this answer on a weekly basis :)

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a pseudo-canonical self-answered FAQ post on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `which`, it should work in both Firefox and Chrome.

Try this:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode + " -- " + e.which + " -- " + e.charCode);

    if(e.which >= 32 && e.which <= 126 ){
        alert(e.which);
    }
};
```