# why result of `charCodeAt(0)` and `e.keyCode` don't match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas why result of `charCodeAt(0)` and `e.keyCode` don't match? and how do I fix this situation?

```
var stop_symbols = $("#words_stop_symbols span").text().split('').map(function (val) {return val.charCodeAt(0);});
    console.dir(stop_symbols);
    //
    $(document).on("keydown", ".quick-edit", function(e) {
        console.dir(e.keyCode);
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode,stop_symbols) != -1) {
            // 
            console.dir("blocked char")
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: and the reason for downvote is? ...

Comment: No idea, got a close vote too. This sounds like a legitimate question imo, especially if there are no duplicates.

Comment: @adeneo My bad, I honestly didn't know that they have different `keyCodes` for different events, my apologies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030532/keypress-and-keyup-why-is-the-keycode-different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the keypress event will work :

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".quick-edit", function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, stop_symbols) != -1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Htve9/)

Comment: @salivan - In my opinion it is, someone else had a different opinion and downvoted my answer, at least until I posted the fiddle as "proof", but this does work just fine as the keypress event and charCodeAt should return the exact same representation of the characters passed (keyup and keydown does not).

Comment: I changed my code to this: $.inArray(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),stop_symbols But it gave me same incorrect results untill I used keypress. So you have the answer. thanks!