# How to make difference between question mark ? and / for azerty keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, keycode

When I bind the <kbd>?</kbd> and the <kbd>/</kbd> key with `javascript` on qwerty keyboard they have the same 
`keycode (191)` but you have to press <kbd>shift</kbd> to do a `?`.

How can I tell which character was pressed on an [**azerty** keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) (layout shown below), as they're different keys, **both** require <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and I get the same keycode for them in `keyup`.:

```
 $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 191) {
            action();
        }
    });
```

[image: Layout]

*(Original image is "KB France" by Yitscar (English Wikipedia) Michka B (French Wikipedia) Licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 via Wikimedia Commons - see use in [the article linked above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY).)*

Comment: Qwerty is not a keyboard layout: is family of several dozen layouts. You should mention at least which country you mean.

Comment: You need to check if Shift is also pressed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: And azerty isn't qwerty (though it's based on it): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: *"But how to do with azerty keyboard, the both key have the same keycode and need shift."*

Comment: This is easy, you either bind to the `keypress` event instead, which will give you different keycodes, or you check `event.shiftKey`

Comment: if (shift is pressed) { someShiftFlag = true; }
if (/ is pressed && someShiftFlag) { // ? is actually pressed }

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: **Again**, the shift key is pressed for **both** of these characters on the azerty keyboard.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there is something specific that makes a difference between these keys.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: I'm sure there is, but it's not whether `Shift` is down as you keep suggesting, and whether the difference is in the information provided to JavaScript by the web browser for the `keyup` and `keydown` events (which are fairly raw) rather than the `keypress` event (translated) is something else entirely. It's no longer maintained, but [this page on the utter madness of keyboard events in JavaScript](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) is a good read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 666) {
        action();
    }
});
```

I don't have an `azerty` keyboard or whatever, so I don't get the same keycodes, but the keypress event will return other keycodes, you'll have to check them yourself.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6XRj/)

Comment: The Keycodes are stored in the event. Why do they have different keycodes for the same key? Can you explain please..

Comment: `keyup` and `keydown` return different keycodes than `keypress`, so using the `keypress` event will return two different keycodes for the two characters, solving the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't `event.charCode` be more reliable?

Comment: For a more thourough explanation, see [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030532/keypress-and-keyup-why-is-the-keycode-different)

Comment: @JuanMendes - jQuery normalizes `event.which`, so not really.

Comment: Yes thanks you very much, with the keypress event the keycode are not the same for ? and / also on azerty keyboard

Comment: @user3884214: Ah, okay, I thought you had a specific reason for using `keyup`. In general, for any keypress that results in a specific character (rather than arrows and such), you want to use `keypress`, not `keyup` and `keydown`, as `keypress` receives the character rather than a keycode.

Answer (score 2):

Check if shift is pressed

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 191 && event.shiftKey) {
            action();
        }
});
```

Note that this is keyboard layout dependent and it will be easier if you can use the `keypress` event as https://stackoverflow.com/a/24995506/227299 suggested

See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for further information

Comment: Yes but this with an azerty keyboard works for "?"and "/". Is there a solution to make a difference ? And thanks for your answer