# evt.which gives different output on keyup and keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).keypress(function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.which)//output is 97 when pressed a   
})
```

But

```
$(window).keyup(function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.which) //output is 65 when pressed a  
})
```

My question is why they are giving different output

Comment: +1 Interested to see the reason!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030532/keypress-and-keyup-why-is-the-keycode-different

Comment: You have 3 specific keyboard event handlers... onkeypress, onkeydown, and onkeyup.

In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

Comment: onkeypress gives you the character code corresponding to the character typed, as opposed to the key code of the key pressed (as it is in keyup and keydown).

Comment: In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed.

Link: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html