# How to put default value to zero when a input number is removed using backspace or using delete button?

Tags: jquery

I have a input number which should always a default value as zero

Incase the user has done a backspace or delete button and removed the value how can i put default value zero as back

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".numbersonly").keypress(function (e) {
     if(this.value.length=='0')
     {
             $(this).val('0');
     return false;
     }

     if(this.value.length==2) return false;

     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).val('0')
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/10265/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put back the 0 if a user leaves the input box and there is no value in it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbersonly").keyup(function(e) {

    if (this.value.length > 2) {
      $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
      $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, this.value.length - 1));
      return false;
    }

  });
  $(".numbersonly").blur(function() {
    console.log("blur")
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).val('0')
    }
  })
});
```

The blur function checks the input box after the user clicks outside of it.

Comment: this code is not working (Could not able to add a new two digit number )

Comment: I have updated my code, and you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/10268/

Comment: thanks , will it make sense to add $(this).focus(); after   $(this).val('0')??

Comment: I don't think it would work, and I don't think it would be a good practices.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup` rather than `keypress`, it solves your problem.

The `keydown` and `keyup` events represent keys being pressed or released, while the `keypress` event represents a character being typed.

Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11030750/2611451

The events are for completely different purposes. Use `keyup` and `keydown` for identifying physical keys and `keypress` for identifying typed characters. The two are fundamentally different tasks with different events; don't try to mix the two. In particular, `keyCode` on `keypress` events is usually redundant and shouldn't be used (except in older IE, but see the linked document below for more on that); for printable keypresses it's usually the same as `which` and `charCode`, although there is some variation between browsers.

Comment: thanks but , this code is not working (Could not able to add a new two digit number )