# Keystroke to ASCII Value

Tags: javascript

I want to take a keystroke and get its ASCII representation. This includes when the SHIFT key is pressed, i.e.

- "shift =" returns 43
- "a" returns 97
- "shift a" returns 65

Is there a way I can do this without writing a lot of code?

Edit:

```js
document.onkeypress = function () {
  console.log(event.which);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function (event) {...`? Otherwise, `event.which` is undefined (or am I wrong?)

Comment: @flen That's correct. Some browsers expose the event as a global window.event, but there are edge cases where it may be the wrong event. Support for window.event is being removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In very **less code**, you can do:

```js
document.onkeypress = function () {
  console.log(event.which);
}
```

Check out your console after running the above code.

> *ps: The weight of the above code is **55 chars**.* `;)`

**Update:** It should be `onkeypress` and not `onkeydown`. Thanks [Timo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5068730/timo).

Comment: For my use case I specifically need ASCII codes, so this does not work.

Comment: @JoshuaSchultheiss As you expected, it returns the right keyCode.

Comment: Oh yeah, the first one is failing. Let me find why. And how did you get `43`?

Comment: It does not return the keyCode differentiating lowercase "a" and uppercase "A." I am making a web app that runs assembly code and to do so I need specific ASCII values.

Comment: @JoshuaSchultheiss I got 65 for `Shift + A`.

Comment: Try lowercase "a" you should get 65. "shift =" should be "+" which has the ASCII value of #43 (I believe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107748/discussion-between-joshua-schultheiss-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: @JoshuaSchultheiss `a` gives me `65`, `Shift + =` gives me `187`.

Comment: You should use `onkeypress` instead of `onkeydown` event, then it works as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here are the decimal encodings for the upper/lower-case "a" in 7-bit ascii (aka us-ascii).

```
char    decimal    hexidecimal
A       65         41  
a       97         61
```

http://www.asciitable.com/

Here's the thing.  keyCode != ascii (necessarily).  Remember lots of different keyboards, languages, etc.  I can select (in software) a us-english layout on a German physical keyboard for instance.  That is at an OS level.

Within the browser the form character encoding defaults to the page encoding (e.g. utf-8, iso-8859-1, etc) unless otherwise specified.

You can use the following snippet to take a look at what is in the keypress event.

```js
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    console.log('charCode: ' + charCode + 
                ' keyIdentifier: ' + e.keyIdentifier + 
                ' which: ' + e.which + 
                ' keyCode: ' + e.keyCode + 
                ' shiftKey: ' + e.shiftKey + 
                ' ctrlKey: ' + e.ctrlKey + 
                ' altKey: ' + e.altKey + 
                ' metaKey: ' + e.metaKey);
}
```

The following answer explains that using keypress event is generally the only reliable way to get a **character code** instead of a **key code**.  And it seems that is what you are after.

[JavaScript KeyCode vs CharCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285627/javascript-keycode-vs-charcode)

Sure enough, using `onkeypress` instead of `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` gives me 65 and 97 for "A" and "a".  You would need to just update your javascript to ignore events from keys you aren't interested in (ie shift, etc).

Interesting experiment would be to play with page encoding and characters outside the 7-bit ascii range and see how well this method works for getting the actual character encodings.