# Convert String Object to integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I have this function:

```
function validar(e) {
  var xx = 1;
  tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;     // 2
  if (tecla == 8) return true;                      // 3
  patron = /[A-Za-z\s]/;                            // 4
  te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);                  // 5

  var valorNumerico = Number(te); 
  if (te > 1 && te < 11) {
    alert('Calificación:' + valorNumerico)
  } else {
    alert('La Calificación debe estar entre 2 y 10  - ' + valorNumerico)
  }
}
```

The goal its catch the input the user and validate the range into 2 to 10

But, shows me `NaN`

I tried `valorNumerico = parseInt(te);`

Shows me `NaN`

I tried `valorNumerico = Integer.parseInt(te);`

Shows me `NaN`

So, how I can convert to integer? thanks I used a function in javascript into asp.net

Comment: how are you declaring `te`? and what is `tecla`?

Comment: What is the value of `te`? Not every string value can be converted to a number. What's your ultimate goal here?

Comment: Seems like te doesn't contain a number

Comment: function validar(e) {
            var xx = 1;
            tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which; // 2
            if (tecla == 8) return true; // 3
            patron = /[A-Za-z\s]/; // 4
            te = String.fromCharCode(tecla); // 5
            var valorNumerico = Number(te); 
            if (te > 1 && te < 11) {
                alert('Calificación:' + valorNumerico)
            } else {
                alert('La Calificación debe estar entre 2 y 10  - ' + valorNumerico)
            }
        }

Comment: @David Ortega Update your question, do not add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

`String.fromCharCode(`) will convert a number (or a series of numbers) into their corresponding sequence of unicode values; so whatever argument you pass to `fromCharCode()` shouldn't actually return a string that you can parse into an integer. In other words, when given a number, `fromCharCode()` will return something that isn't a numeric value.

I would do as others suggest and `console.log(tecla)` and `console.log(e)` to see what values you're really dealing with.

If you really are listening to a keyup or keydown event, then `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` should be parseable by `parseInt()`. For example, if `e.keycode` returned the value `0x31`, you should be able to to parse that into a string with `fromCharCode()` and into an integer with `parseInt()`.

However, logging will always be your best bet when you're not quite sure what data you're dealing with, or if things just seem strange.

Comment: in other words i cant use this function for my porpouses.? So how can i implemented a function to validate the range input the user in a text box. thanks

Comment: You can totally use the function for your purposes, it just depends upon if you're passing it valid data. `String.fromCharCode(0x31)` will return "1" and you can `parseInt(1)` to get the integer value of 1. You need to verify and validate that you're actually passing in a valid keycode that corresponds to a number to `String.fromCharCode()`

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` doesn't always assume base 10. That could be part of it.

But I really suspect here that `tecla` and `te` do **not** have the values you think they do. Try putting a `console.log()` statement right above your `parseInt()` call, so you can see what's really going to that function. It might surprise you.

You especially should read through this related question:

> [JavaScript KeyCode vs CharCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285627/javascript-keycode-vs-charcode)

Which tells you that this line:

```
tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
```

Should perhaps look more like this:

```
tecla  = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode
```

But even that still might not produce what you want for certain older browsers and non-printable characters, or if you're using something other than the `keypress` even, like `keyup` or `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in these lines:

```
1) te = String.fromCharCode(tecla); // 5
2) var valorNumerico = Number(te);
```

Lookingat your code line1 seems to suggest that tecla is a number, also it should be as fromCharCode() function expects a number and returns a character;
So let's say tecla is 65, so line1 would return 'A' that would be assigned to te variable.

Now in line2 you are trying to convert the character into a number, since (for e.g. A) it is not convertible to a number, you get NaN.

Hope it helps!