# Getting character and code from keyPressed

Tags: javascript, html

```
function convert(){
    String.fromCharCode();
    var out = document.getElementById("");
}


document.getElementById("=").addEventListener("keypress", convert);
```

The result should be the

I'm new to javascript and have this assignment, which has to be done exactly the way it's asked. I tried myself for a couple of hours, but I still need some help !

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Inside your event handler, you can use `event.keyCode` to get the Unicode value of the pressed key. [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp)

Comment: What does "Slide 39" says?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript KeyCode vs CharCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285627/javascript-keycode-vs-charcode)

Answer (score 1):

- Use `insertAdjacentHTML` (instead of `el.innerHTML += html`)
- Attach your event listener to `window` or `document`

## Using `insertAdjacentHTML()`

```js
const EL_output = document.getElementById("output"); // Cache selector

function convert(ev) {
  const html = `You pressed ${ev.key} character code ${ev.keyCode}<br>`;
  EL_output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', convert);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

## Using `Element.innerHTML` and `+=`

```js
const EL_output = document.getElementById("output"); // Cache selector

function convert(ev) {
  const html = `You pressed ${ev.key} character code ${ev.keyCode}<br>`;
  EL_output.innerHTML += html;
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', convert);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

PS:

to attach the event listener to the actual `#output` element add the `tabindex="0"` attribute: `<div id="output" tabindex="0"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

A little trick with CSS and `\n` new line char, to insert text, instead of HTML:

```js
let out = document.getElementById("output");

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
  let message = `Pressed: ${char}, char code: ${e.charCode}\n`;
  
  out.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', message);
  out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight;
});
```

```css
#output {
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
Press any key...
<p id="output"></p>
```

Any changes with `innerHTML` or `innerText` / `textContent` - in fact rewrite all contents... `insertAdjacent` method only inserts a little piece.